# Passing only one word from a TextBox to another TextBox

Tags: c#

for example I have TextBox1 and TextBox2

TextBox1.Text has "John Doe"

and TextBox2.Text will have "John" or whatever what is the first word found in TextBox1.

In what way can I only pass the first word in the TextBox1 to TextBox2?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow.

First of all, I suggest you do some research of your own and make an attempt at solving the problem. To get you started, you can use `string.Split()` method to split content of `TextBox1.Text` and assign the first word to `TextBox2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach an event handler to the `TextChanged` event on `TextBox1`. This allows you to automatically update the text in `TextBox2` when the value of `TextBox1` changes.

From there the text is split by the space character to break apart the words in the string and we take the first element in the resulting array, which would be the first word, or null if there were no words at all.

```
TextBox1.TextChanged += (sender, args) => TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text.Split(' ').FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This solution will overwrite whatever value is in TextBox2 with the first word from TextBox1.

Answer (score 0):

The event handler method (as proposed by Connor above) is an Always On situation.

If you want this to occur under user control so then a button with an on-click event (essentially doing what Connor suggested the event handler would do) will achieve this.

You could then easily go overboard with radio buttions in a group to determine whether it should copy first, last, middle, Initial etc. etc.

The most important thing you need to do (before coding it) is to decide when and how you want something to occur and what that something actually is (i.e. a bit of analysis up front can save a lot of dev time downstream).

Then you can address the technical solution that meets all those requirements :-)